# Command similar to netstat -np but grouped by state and PID?

Tags: linux, rhel, netstat

Is there a command similar to `netstat -np` but grouped by **state** and **PID**?

I'd like to know the current count of server connections in a particular state grouped by Programs.

similar to,

```
102 squid ESTABLISHED
32 httpd ESTABLISHED
```

I use RHEL5.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `sort` to reorganize the output of `netstat` in any format you like.

```
$ netstat -anpt 2>&1 | tail -n +5 | sort -k7,7 -k 6,6
```

This will sort the output using the 7th column first (the process name/PID) followed by the state (ESTABLISHED, LISTEN, etc.).

**NOTE:** The first part of the command, `netstat -anpt 2>&1 | tail -n +5 ..` will direct all the output that may occur on STDOUT to STDIN as well and then chop off the first 5 lines which are boilerplate output from `netstat` which we are uninterested in.

#### Example

```
$ netstat -anpt 2>&1 | tail -n +5 | sort -k7,7 -k 6,6
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.20:49309      192.168.1.103:631       ESTABLISHED 2077/gnome-settings 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.20:38393      204.62.14.135:443       ESTABLISHED 2260/mono           
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.20:39738      74.125.192.125:5222     ESTABLISHED 2264/pidgin         
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.20:40097      87.117.201.130:6667     ESTABLISHED 2264/pidgin         
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.20:53920      217.168.150.38:6667     ESTABLISHED 2264/pidgin         
...
tcp        1      0 192.168.1.20:50135      190.93.247.58:80        CLOSE_WAIT  24714/google-chrome 
tcp        1      0 192.168.1.20:44420      192.168.1.103:631       CLOSE_WAIT  24714/google-chrome 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.20:36892      74.125.201.188:5228     ESTABLISHED 24714/google-chrome 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.20:43778      74.125.192.125:5222     ESTABLISHED 24714/google-chrome 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.20:33749      198.252.206.140:80      ESTABLISHED 24714/google-chrome 
...
```

You can use a similar approach to get the counts using various tools such as `wc` or `uniq -c`.

#### Changing the output

If you'd really like to get the output of `netstat` looking like this:

```
102 squid ESTABLISHED
32 httpd ESTABLISHED
```

You can do some further slicing and dicing using `awk` & `sed`. This can be made more compact, but should get you started and does the job.

```
$ netstat -anpt 2>&1 | tail -n +5 | awk '{print $7,$6}' | sort -k1,1 -k3,3 \
    | sed 's#/# #' | column -t
2264   pidgin          ESTABLISHED
2264   pidgin          ESTABLISHED
24714  google-chrome   CLOSE_WAIT
24714  google-chrome   CLOSE_WAIT
24714  google-chrome   ESTABLISHED
24714  google-chrome   ESTABLISHED
...
24714  google-chrome   ESTABLISHED
26358  ssh             ESTABLISHED
26358  ssh             ESTABLISHED
26358  ssh             ESTABLISHED
26358  ssh             LISTEN
26358  ssh             LISTEN
26358  ssh             LISTEN
```

**NOTE:** `column -t` simply aligns all the output in nice columns.

#### Counting the connections

Finally to do what you want in terms of tallying the occurrences:

```
$ netstat -anpt 2>&1 | tail -n +5 | awk '{print $7,$6}' | sort -k1,1 -k3,3 \
    | sed 's#/# #' | column -t | uniq -c
  6 -      LISTEN
  8 -      TIME_WAIT
  1 2077   gnome-settings  ESTABLISHED
  1 2260   mono            ESTABLISHED
 10 2264   pidgin          ESTABLISHED
  2 24714  google-chrome   CLOSE_WAIT
 27 24714  google-chrome   ESTABLISHED
  3 26358  ssh             ESTABLISHED
  4 26358  ssh             LISTEN
  1 26359  ssh             ESTABLISHED
  4 3042   thunderbird     ESTABLISHED
  1 32472  monodevelop     ESTABLISHED
  2 32472  monodevelop     LISTEN
  1 32533  mono            ESTABLISHED
  1 32533  mono            LISTEN
  1 3284   monodevelop     LISTEN
  1 3365   mono            LISTEN
  1 4528   mono            LISTEN
  1 8416   dropbox         ESTABLISHED
  1 8416   dropbox         LISTEN
```

The first column represents the counts.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer - I'll vote up when I have 15 rep

Answer (score 5):

from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat)

> On Linux, `netstat` (part of "net-tools") is **deprecated**, `ss` (part of iproute2) should be used instead.

The *net-tools* package has not seen a Linux release in more than a decade. That's a long time to go without an update for a program suite designed to manage and monitor an ever-evolving kernel's communications interfaces - especially when you're talking about the kernel that practically runs the internet.

Thankfully though, there is the actively maintained *iproute2* package - which includes the `ss` utility.

With `ss` you can do the thing you ask for like:

```
ss -np state ESTABLISHED
```

from `man ss`:

```
#USAGE EXAMPLES
   ss -t -a
#          Display all TCP sockets.
#
   ss -t -a -Z
#          Display all TCP sockets with process SELinux
#          security contexts.
#
   ss -u -a
#          Display all UDP sockets.
#
   ss -o state established '( dport = :ssh or sport  =   :ssh )'
#          Display all established ssh connections.
#
   ss -x src /tmp/.X11-unix/*
#          Find  all  local  processes  connected  to X server.
#
   ss -o state fin-wait-1 '( sport = :http or sport  = :https )' dst 193.233.7/24
#          List all the tcp sockets in state FIN-WAIT-1
#          for our apache to network  193.233.7/24  and
#          look at their timers.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use netstat, column, and awk:

```
netstat -anpt | column -t | awk '{print $1,$6,$7}'
```

This prints the first,sixth,and seventh column.

```
tcp LISTEN -
tcp LISTEN -
tcp ESTABLISHED 2084/firefox
tcp ESTABLISHED 2084/firefox
tcp6 LISTEN -
```

Answer (score -1):

I really appreciate this kind of help, so It is time to colaborate:

```
netstat -tun | grep 1521 | awk '{print $6}' | uniq -c
```

result:
[image]

Comment: I don't see the PIDs in your output...?